# Join overlapping features and store each joined object in one layer

Tags: qgis, merge, spatial-join

I am using QGIS. And I drew a buffer for the link data. What I want is to combine buffers which have overlapping areas each other to create new objects.

For example, you want to automatically merge two nested and selected objects into one object.

[image]

I want to recognize duplicate objects, merge them, and store them in one layer. Of course, I know how to directly select and merge overlapping objects, but I'm sure it'll take too long to combine about 300,000 objects. Therefore, I want to know how to automatically recognize duplicate objects and merge the recognized objects into one object.

Is there a way to automate it so that I don't do it myself. Or how can I perform it using a GIS program (ArcMap, etc.)?

Comment: Are you asking how to `dissolve` a layer, maybe based on an attribute?

Comment: Yes, and the attribute is whether there is an intersection of buffer A and buffer B.